# Cannot use fillna when a condition is introduced - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle, fillna

Given the following DataFrame:

```
d = {'A': [1,2,np.nan, -2, -1], 'B':[5,-1,np.nan,2,-1], 'C':[1,2,3,4,-1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need to replace all values less then 0 from column B by np.nan (for instance); I've tried:

```
df  = df.apply(lambda x: fillna(value = np.nan) if x < 0)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-157-2d34a150c603>", line 1
  df  = df.apply(lambda x: fillna(value = np.nan) if x < 0)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Maybe `if x < 0: fillna(value = np.nan)`

Comment: Use `df.loc[df.B < 1, 'B'] = np.nan`

Comment: when i tried the other way around it gives me: ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index A')

Comment: @Barmar that still won't be valid syntax inside a lambda. You would need an else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for i in range (0,len(df.columns)):
    x=df.columns[i]
    df[df[x]<0]=np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a mask:

```
df.loc[df['B'] < 0, 'B'] = np.nan

print(df)

     A    B  C
0  1.0  5.0  1
1  2.0  NaN  2
2  NaN  NaN  3
3 -2.0  2.0  4
4 -1.0  NaN -1
```